"chromedriver" binary not found for Symfony Panther package
I've installed it using this:
composer require --dev dbrekelmans/bdi && vendor/bin/bdi detect drivers

And I tried this:
composer require dbrekelmans/bdi && vendor/bin/bdi detect drivers

And I also tried installing like this:
sudo snap install chromium --devmode

Panther always complains it can't find the driver but it is definitely installed:
at vendor/symfony/panther/src/ProcessManager/ChromeManager.php:92
     88▕         if ($binary = (new ExecutableFinder())->find('chromedriver', null, ['./drivers', './vendor/bin'])) {
     89▕             return $binary;
     90▕         }
     91▕
  ➜  92▕         throw new \RuntimeException('"chromedriver" binary not found. Install it using the package manager of your operating system or by running "composer require --dev dbrekelmans/bdi && vendor/bin/bdi detect drivers".');
     93▕     }
     94▕
     95▕     private function getDefaultArguments(): array
     96▕     {

When I run vendor/bin/bdi detect drivers I get this:
[OK] chromedriver 123.0.6312.122 installed to drivers/chromedriver

Why can't Panther detect or use the Chrome driver?
Running this on Ubuntu with PHP 8.2. I'm not using a Docker image.

Found the solution here:
https://skolo.online/documents/webscrapping/
But installed the latest version from here:
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/
First install Chrome:
sudo apt update

wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

sudo apt install wget

sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install -f

google-chrome --version

Then install the Chrome driver:
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/123.0.6312.122/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip

unzip chromedriver-linux64.zip

sudo mv chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/chromedriver
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver

